# Pillow, OpenJPEG (for jpeg2000) and anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library, jpeg2000

I'm trying to save an image with JPEG2000 from pillow, but get the dreaded `OSError: encoder jpeg2k not available`.

Now following the instructions in [pillow's docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000), I installed OpenJPEG. I tried both [from conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openjpeg) and following [their installation guide](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

After each try I uninstalled, cleaned the conda cache, and reinstalled pillow:

`conda uninstall pillow -y && conda clean -a -y && conda install pillow -y`

The problem persists. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on Window's WSL2.

I'd prefer running OpenJPEG from anaconda, to keep the project workable off of the `environment.yml` alone.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would [file an issue on Conda Forge's pillow-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/pillow-feedstock/issues). I'm a bit confused that [their `build.sh`](https://github.com/conda-forge/pillow-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/build.sh) has a commented out line for JPEG2K. I'm not familiar with the compilation details for `pillow`, but `pillow` may need to know about the availability of a JPEG2K library during installation. The feedstock authors may also be interested in knowing that JPEG2K support isn't working out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`. Using `openjpeg=2.4.0` [openjpeg](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openjpeg) and `Pillow=8.1.0` with `Python 3.7.6` didn't solve the issue (latest version of the packages).

I had to install low level libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev
```

Then I recreated the conda env and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenJpeg on Mac, you can use Mac Ports:

```
sudo port install openjpeg
```

To install libjpeg on Mac OSX use Brew:

```
brew install jpeg
```

Mac Ports can be installed here:
https://www.macports.org/

Brew can be installed here:
https://brew.sh/