# How to install OpenJPEG on MacOS, for use with JP2 files and Pillow

Tags: python, cmake, python-imaging-library, jpeg2000

There are some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184995/how-do-i-install-openjpeg-on-windows-and-use-it-with-pillow) and especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65394298/pillow-openjpeg-for-jpeg2000-and-anaconda), but they don't go into quite the detail I'm seeking.

I'm attempting to read and edit JP2 (aka, JPEG2000) files using pillow. My code is below, and I suppose I don't yet have the OpenJPEG library installed, because I get the error `module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'jpeg2k_decoder'`. So, I believe that I neeed to install OpenJPEG. Because I it's a system install (not contained within a virtual environment) and the instructions are piecemeal, I'm hoping to get more info.

[Pillow's documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000) indicates:

> To enable JPEG 2000 support, you need to build and install the OpenJPEG library, version 2.0.0 or higher, before building the Python Imaging Library.

And OpenJPEG's [install instructions](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md) aren't very clear, but seems to also require installation of [cmake](https://cmake.org/install/). The general advice I see everywhere is to uninstall pillow, install the OpenJPEG library, and then reinstall pillow. And I see that people often have to troubleshoot because pillow's reinstall doesn't pick up the new library sometimes.

I'm hoping that those who have been through the process on a Mac can advise on some details:

1. cmake appears to be required for installing OpenJPEG. Are the instructions at https://cmake.org/install/ sufficient?
2. The [OpenJPEG instructions](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md) don't seem complete. Has anyone made step by step instructions that are easier to follow?

Code that returns the error:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/data/batches/dlc_golf_ver01/data/sn84025891/100493731/1901082401/0132.jp2'
img_raw = requests.get(url)    
img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_raw.content))
display(img)


------ Outputs an error including: -------
AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'jpeg2k_decoder'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the easiest way to manage packages under **macOS**, such as **OpenJPEG**, is with **homebrew**.

All you need is:

```
brew install openjpeg
```

Search for available packages containing "jp" with:

```
brew search jp
```

**Sample Output**

```
==> Formulae
jp              jpdfbookmarks   jpeg-archive    jpeg-xl ✔       jpegoptim       mjpegtools      openjpeg ✔      recoverjpeg
jp2a            jpeg ✔          jpeg-turbo ✔    jpeginfo        jpegrescan      mozjpeg         pjproject
```

Get info about a package with:

```
brew info openjpeg
```

**Sample Output**

```
openjpeg: stable 2.4.0 (bottled), HEAD
Library for JPEG-2000 image manipulation
https://www.openjpeg.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0 (523 files, 13.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-11-25 at 16:35:14
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjpeg.rb
License: BSD-2-Clause
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, doxygen ✘
Required: libpng ✔, libtiff ✔, little-cms2 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 82,101 (30 days), 247,510 (90 days), 1,217,811 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,835 (30 days), 5,246 (90 days), 20,835 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Check what files are in a package with:

```
brew ls openjpeg
```

**Sample Output**

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/bin/opj_compress
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/bin/opj_decompress
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/bin/opj_dump
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/include/openjpeg-2.4/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/lib/libopenjp2.2.4.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/lib/openjpeg-2.4/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/lib/pkgconfig/libopenjp2.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/lib/ (3 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/share/doc/ (497 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/share/man/ (4 files)
```

---

Check how PIL is configured with:

```
python3 -m PIL        # or use "pythonXXX -m PIL" if that's how you start Python
```

**Sample Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 9.0.1
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 9.0.1
--- TKINTER support ok, loaded 8.6
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.11.1
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.13
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.2.2
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for libjpeg-turbo 2.1.2
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.4.0
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.11
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.2.0
*** RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support not installed
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BLP
Extensions: .blp
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BMP image/bmp
Extensions: .bmp
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BUFR
Extensions: .bufr
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CUR
Extensions: .cur
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DCX
Extensions: .dcx
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DDS
Extensions: .dds
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DIB image/bmp
Extensions: .dib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EPS application/postscript
Extensions: .eps, .ps
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FITS
Extensions: .fit, .fits
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FLI
Extensions: .flc, .fli
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FTEX
Extensions: .ftc, .ftu
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GBR
Extensions: .gbr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GIF image/gif
Extensions: .gif
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GRIB
Extensions: .grib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5
Extensions: .h5, .hdf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICNS image/icns
Extensions: .icns
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICO image/x-icon
Extensions: .ico
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IM
Extensions: .im
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IMT
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IPTC
Extensions: .iim
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG image/jpeg
Extensions: .jfif, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG2000 image/jp2
Extensions: .j2c, .j2k, .jp2, .jpc, .jpf, .jpx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MCIDAS
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MPEG video/mpeg
Extensions: .mpeg, .mpg
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MSP
Extensions: .msp
Features: open, save, decode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCD
Extensions: .pcd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCX image/x-pcx
Extensions: .pcx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIXAR
Extensions: .pxr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PNG image/png
Extensions: .apng, .png
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PPM image/x-portable-anymap
Extensions: .pbm, .pgm, .pnm, .ppm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PSD image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
Extensions: .psd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SGI image/sgi
Extensions: .bw, .rgb, .rgba, .sgi
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SPIDER
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SUN
Extensions: .ras
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TGA image/x-tga
Extensions: .icb, .tga, .vda, .vst
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TIFF image/tiff
Extensions: .tif, .tiff
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WEBP image/webp
Extensions: .webp
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WMF
Extensions: .emf, .wmf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XBM image/xbm
Extensions: .xbm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XPM image/xpm
Extensions: .xpm
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XVTHUMB
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, although OpenJPEG is not a python library. The python library to which you refer is a wrapper and installing it does not install the actual OpenJPEG.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Have a look at the end of my answer here for building Pillow under macOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969447/2836621